# Performing a prefix computation using SQL without defined procedures

Tags: sql, sqlite, prefix

I have a table with a column of integers - I need a way to generate the "prefix" of this column in another table.

For e.g.

I have 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 as the input
I need 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 as the output

This needs to be done in SQLite's SQL dialect , no user defined functions or stored procedures are possible.

Comment: can you explain the logic you use that gets you from `1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0` to `1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3`? is this like a running total?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is "prefix" of the column? So it is not clear how you generated output based on input.

Comment: Ok it is clean now (after update). So you need sum of previous elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
select value,
(select sum(t2.value) from table t2 where t2.id <= t1.id ) as accumulated
from table t1
```

from: [SQLite: accumulator (sum) column in a SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785995/sqlite-accumulator-sum-column-in-a-select-statement/3786711#3786711)

Answer (score 1):

So to insert from `input` table to `output` table you need following query:

```
INSERT INTO output
SELECT id,
(SELECT sum(i1.value) FROM input AS i1 WHERE i1.rowid  <= i2.rowid) as VALUE
FROM input AS i2
```