# How to select values, where each one depends on a previously aggregated state?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
|-----|-----|
| i d | val |
|-----|-----|
|  1  |  1  |
|-----|-----|
|  2  |  4  |
|-----|-----|
|  3  |  3  |
|-----|-----|
|  4  |  7  |
|-----|-----|
```

Can I get the following output:

```
|-----|
| sum |
|-----|
|  1  |
|-----|
|  5  |
|-----|
|  8  |
|-----|
| 1 5 |
|-----|
```

using a single SQLite3 SELECT-query? I know it could be easily achieved using variables, but SQLite3 lacks those. Maybe some recursive query? Thanks.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785995/sqlite-accumulator-sum-column-in-a-select-statement

Answer (score 0):

No.

In a relational database table rows do not have any order. If you specify an order for the rows, then it's possible to write a query.

Now, you could add an extra column to sort the rows. For example:

```
| val | sort
|-----|-----
|  1  |  10
|  4  |  20
|  3  |  30
|  7  |  40
```

The query could be:

```
select
  sum(val) over(order by sort)
from my_table
```

Comment: Updated to contain a primary key for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

For the updated question, you can write:

```
select
  sum(val) over(order by id)
from my_table
```

Comment: @ababo You're probably using an old version of sqlite that doesn't support window functions.

Answer (score 0):

By using the order of the `id` column and if you want only the `sum` column, you can do this:

```
select (select sum(val) from tablename where id <= t.id) sum
from tablename t
```

Comment: This should be bloody inefficient.

Comment: If and when you find a solution to your problem, then question its efficiency.