# How to do a rolling sum, each row need to include the sum of previous rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table [visit]. I need to get the rows grouped by user_id with sum of visit_duration_seconds for when order_number is null, for example, for user [2875636] i'll get: 61+151+33+13. Each row should include the sum of the rows before it.
Plz also refer RESULT column in expected result below

> ```
> user_id   starttime           visit_duration_seconds  order_number
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:03:50 61  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:08:18 151 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:15:43 33  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:16:37 13  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:18:01 2011                     10177888
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:24:35 1172                     10177884
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:32:03 4731    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:33:27 407 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:37:29 74  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 18:48:55 80  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:05:00 1955    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:14:12 326 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:23:39 972 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:33:05 5440    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:35:48 43  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:41:10 66  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:42:03 100 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:42:12 2414                     10177940
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:49:05 432                  10177925
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:50:19 183 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:52:46 2061    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 19:52:53 400 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:00:47 338 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:08:58 216 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:14:21 58  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:14:26 196 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:19:14 2189    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:21:29 424 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 20:24:42 999 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:01:39 1810    
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:02:54 525 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:10:06 27  
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:12:08 282 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 21:51:02 6   
> 2875636   2013-01-16 22:18:34 173 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 23:02:58 318 
> 2875636   2013-01-16 23:45:37 207 
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:01:45 18  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:16:45 39  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:22:55 656 
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:25:54 1852    
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:29:23 688 
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:47:26 2258                       10177846
> 3018868   2013-01-16 16:57:41 572 
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:06:47 1431    
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:18:32 29  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:21:57 45  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:29:23 16  
> 3018868   2013-01-16 17:36:47 490
> ```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
user_id starttime           visit_duration_seconds  order_number        RESULT
2875636 2013-01-16 18:03:50 61                                      61
2875636 2013-01-16 18:08:18 151                                     212
2875636 2013-01-16 18:15:43 33                                      245
2875636 2013-01-16 18:16:37 13                                      258
2875636 2013-01-16 18:18:01 2011                     10177888           0
2875636 2013-01-16 18:24:35 1172                     10177884           0
2875636 2013-01-16 18:32:03 4731                                        4731
2875636 2013-01-16 18:33:27 407                                     5138
2875636 2013-01-16 18:37:29 74                                      5212
2875636 2013-01-16 18:48:55 80                                      ...
2875636 2013-01-16 19:05:00 1955                                        ...
2875636 2013-01-16 19:14:12 326                                     ...
2875636 2013-01-16 19:23:39 972 
2875636 2013-01-16 19:33:05 5440    
2875636 2013-01-16 19:35:48 43  
2875636 2013-01-16 19:41:10 66  
2875636 2013-01-16 19:42:03 100 
2875636 2013-01-16 19:42:12 2414                     10177940
2875636 2013-01-16 19:49:05 432                  10177925
2875636 2013-01-16 19:50:19 183 
2875636 2013-01-16 19:52:46 2061    
2875636 2013-01-16 19:52:53 400 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:00:47 338 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:08:58 216 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:14:21 58  
2875636 2013-01-16 20:14:26 196 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:19:14 2189    
2875636 2013-01-16 20:21:29 424 
2875636 2013-01-16 20:24:42 999 
2875636 2013-01-16 21:01:39 1810    
2875636 2013-01-16 21:02:54 525 
2875636 2013-01-16 21:10:06 27  
2875636 2013-01-16 21:12:08 282 
2875636 2013-01-16 21:51:02 6   
2875636 2013-01-16 22:18:34 173 
2875636 2013-01-16 23:02:58 318 
2875636 2013-01-16 23:45:37 207 
3018868 2013-01-16 16:01:45 18  
3018868 2013-01-16 16:16:45 39  
3018868 2013-01-16 16:22:55 656 
3018868 2013-01-16 16:25:54 1852    
3018868 2013-01-16 16:29:23 688 
3018868 2013-01-16 16:47:26 2258                       10177846
3018868 2013-01-16 16:57:41 572 
3018868 2013-01-16 17:06:47 1431    
3018868 2013-01-16 17:18:32 29  
3018868 2013-01-16 17:21:57 45  
3018868 2013-01-16 17:29:23 16  
3018868 2013-01-16 17:36:47 490
```

Comment: I did a similar job with with SQLite, using an Inner Join. I suggest you take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675079/sqlite-filtering-by-sum/3681524#3681524 (forget the delete part)

Comment: @MPelletier: the semi-join approach is workable for reasonable sized sets. With large sets, that approach has the potential to produce an unwieldy number of rows. Another approach is to use a correlated subquery, but that also has a significant performance disadvantage with large sets.

Comment: @spencer7593 Yes, that's true. Not knowing the size of the data, I thought I could throw it in there.

Comment: @MPelletier: it's good to have several tools in the toolbelt. Analytic functions would be another appropriate answer, if only MySQL supported them. I'm having trouble wrapping by brain around the join criteria that would include only earlier rows back to the latest non-NULL order_number. I get it with a correlated subquery, just not with a join operation. It's probably possible, I just haven't figured it out yet.)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of MySQL user variables to emulate analytic functions. (There are some other approaches as well, like using a semi-join or using a correlated subquery. I can provide solutions for those as well, if you feel they may be more appropriate.)

For emulating a "running total" analytic function, try something like this:

```
SELECT t.user_id
     , t.starttime
     , t.order_number
     , IF(t.order_number IS NOT NULL,
         @tot_dur := 0,
         @tot_dur := @tot_dur + t.visit_duration_seconds) AS tot_dur
  FROM visit t
  JOIN (SELECT @tot_dur := 0) d
 ORDER BY t.user_id, t.start_time
```

The "trick" here is to use an IF function to test whether or not `order_number` is null. When it's null, we add the duration value to the variable, otherwise, we set the variable to zero.

We use an inline view (aliased as `d`, to ensure that the @tot_dur variable is initialized to zero.

NOTE: Take care with using MySQL user variables like this. In the SELECT statement as above, the assignment of the variables in the SELECT list happens after the ORDER BY, so we can get deterministic behavior.

---

That query does not handle "breaks" in user_id.  To get that, we are going to need the value of user_id from the previous row. We can preserve that in another user variable. The order of the operations is deterministic, and we need to take care to do the accumulation BEFORE we overwrite the user_id from the previous row.

We either need to reorder the columns so that user_id appears after tot_dur (or include a second copy of the user_id column)

```
SELECT t.user_id
     , t.starttime
     , t.order_number
     , IF(t.order_number IS NULL,
         @tot_dur := IF(@prev_user_id = t.user_id,@tot_dur,0) + t.visit_duration_seconds,
         @tot_dur := 0
       ) AS tot_dur
     , @prev_user_id := t.user_id AS prev_user_id
  FROM visit t
  JOIN (SELECT @tot_dur := 0, @prev_user_id := NULL) d
 ORDER BY t.user_id, t.start_time
```

The values returned in the `user_id` and `prev_user_id` columns is identical.  That "extra" column could be removed, or the columns could be reordered by wrapping the query (as an inline view) in another query, although this comes at a performance cost:

```
SELECT v.user_id
     , v.starttime
     , v.order_number
     , v.tot_dur
  FROM (SELECT t.starttime
             , t.order_number
             , IF(t.order_number IS NULL,
                 @tot_dur := IF(@prev_user_id = t.user_id,@tot_dur,0) + t.visit_duration_seconds,
                 @tot_dur := 0
               ) AS tot_dur
             , @prev_user_id := t.user_id AS user_id
          FROM visit t
          JOIN (SELECT @tot_dur := 0, @prev_user_id := NULL) d
         ORDER BY t.user_id, t.start_time
       ) v
```

That query demonstrates that it is possible for MySQL to return the specified resultset. But for optimum performance, we'd want to run just the query in the inline view (aliased as `v`), and handle the re-ordering of the columns (putting the user_id column first) on the client side, when the rows are retrieved.

The other two common approaches are using a semi-join, and using a correlated subquery, although these approaches can be more resource intensive when processing large sets.

Comment: The query given in the answer does NOT account for changes in the user_id value, which is probably not the desired behavior. I will modify the query, to handle a "break" when the user_id value changes. (The order of the columns in the resultset will be impacted,

Comment: u might as well use the same trick with the variable.. I did not understand the JOIN u have there

Comment: There were a couple of problems in the queries in the answer that have  now been fixed (a missing comma in the IF function, user variable names did not match, table alias not matched, etc.  I think the queries are right now.

Comment: The purpose of the JOIN is to initialize the user variables. Since MySQL will materialize the inline view ("derived table") before the outer query runs, we are guaranteed that `@tot_dur` and `@prev_user_id` variables are initialized when rows from `visit` are processed. It would also be possible to run a separate `SET`  statement to initialize the variables, but my preference is to have the required initialization included in the query.