# sql query for each day

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i have a table main:

```
(  
time date,  
qty int  
)
```

i want to create a query so for each day i get the sum of qty on that day and all days before that
so for this data

```
-----------------------    
time        | qty    
01/09/2009  | 3   
02/09/2009  | 8  
03/09/2009  | 2 
04/09/2009  | 5
```

i get:

```
-----------------------    
time        | total    
01/09/2009  | 3   
02/09/2009  | 11  
03/09/2009  | 13 
04/09/2009  | 18
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the following post for an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596107/how-to-do-a-rolling-sum-each-row-need-to-include-the-sum-of-previous-rows

Comment: do you have any primary key in you table?

Comment: @Praveen yes i didnt mensioned it, its (id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a faster result

```
SELECT time
     , @tot_qty := @tot_qty+qty AS tot_qty
FROM Table1 
JOIN (SELECT @tot_qty := 0) d
order by time
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b3e2/7)**

Comment: @SiavashM please check my answer. I am sure it would give you faster result.

Comment: i checked it it works perfectly, thank you but a quick question what if i have multiple records for each day?

Comment: @SiavashM In case of multiple records you need to use **`group by`**. Give me some dummy records and i will get back to you.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5867504/ dont know if it's in right format tell me if it's not

Comment: why cant i mention you in a comment @Luv Luv?

Comment: @SiavashM you did mention me in comment. Lets get to the point. See my **[update Query here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc66/3)** I have added a new record. This time i am not sure about Performance.

Comment: Thx a lot, you helped a lot, it works perfectly and is faster that prev.one executed on 109k rows of data on .28sec

Comment: @SiavashM I am Glad it helped you. Welcome to SO. But i request you to put some effort before asking a Question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIME, (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM main m2 WHERE m2.ITME <= mt1.TIME) AS sum  
FROM main m1  
ORDER BY TIME
```

This should do the trick, though it might not be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  M.Time,
  SUM(M2.Qty) RunningTotal
FROM
  Main M
  LEFT JOIN Main M2 ON M.Time >= M2.Time
GROUP BY
  M.Time;
```